# Dynamic Messagebox - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: excel, vba

I have two macros assigned to buttons that do basically the same thing. They draw info from cells in another worksheet ("Combined") based on the active cell ("Property Name") then display them in a message box. The second macro is giving me a runtime error 5 on the line beginning with "maturity".

```vb
Sub PropertyInfo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ArrayRange As Variant
Dim ActCell As Variant

Set ActCell = ActiveCell
PropertyName = ActiveCell.Value

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True Or IsNumeric(ActiveCell) = True Then
    MsgBox "Please select Property Name"    
Else
    Sheets("Combined").Select
    ArrayRange = Sheets("Combined").Range(Range("F1"), Range("F1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    Sheets("Pivot").Select

    Maturity = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActCell, ArrayRange, 36, False)
    Lender = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActCell, ArrayRange, 41, False)
    Originator = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActCell, ArrayRange, 42, False)
    Address = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActCell, ArrayRange, 2, False)

    MsgBox "Property Name: " & PropertyName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Loan Maturity: " & Maturity & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Lender: " & Lender & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Originator: " & Originator & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Property Address: " & Address & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Note: If dates are blank, the database doesnt have the info."

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If

End Sub
```

end result will display the messagebox with Maturity, Lender, Originator, and Address

Comment: *Where* is the error ?

Comment: Sorry - the error is on the line beginning with "maturity"

Comment: It's possible that vlookup isn't finding a match.  What's the text of the error message?  And what's different about this Sub from the one which works?

Comment: You definitely got 36 columns in your ArrayRange?

Comment: @Skin yes, definitely 36 columns. Even if i change 36 to a lower number, same result

Comment: @TimWilliams the only difference is that the data is pulled from different columns and named different things. The error is runtime error 5, invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: If you comment out the problem line does the next one run with no error? Where/how is Maturity declred?

Comment: @TimWilliams No, the next line has same issue. In this case "Lender"

Comment: Try adding `Debug.Print Sheets("Combined").Range(Range("F1"), Range("F1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Address` is the output what you expect?

Comment: @TimWilliams I added that before the line where i was getting an error and am now getting an error on your code. Error 1004 application defined or object defined error

Comment: Add the line before you switch sheets - that's a whole other thing in your code which could be fixed - you should not rely on specific sheets being activated/selected or your code can become unreliable - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: @TimWilliams I got an error when adding it before switching as well.. I included "On error resume next" in front of the lines where i set maturity with vlookups and it removed the error message but the values are still blank. It looks like the code is not retrieving the vlookup correctly

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use an array in this case.

Try something like this instead:

```
Sub PropertyInfo()
    Dim lf2
    Dim PropertyName As Variant, m, shtCombined As Worksheet

    lf2 = vbLf & vbLf

    Set shtCombined = Sheets("Combined")
    PropertyName = ActiveCell.Value

    If Len(PropertyName) = 0 Or IsNumeric(PropertyName) = True Then
        MsgBox "Please select Property Name"
    Else
        'find the matching row number
        m = Application.Match(PropertyName, shtCombined.Range("F:F"), 0)

        If Not IsError(m) Then       '<< found a match?
            With shtCombined.Rows(m)
                '###adjust the column numbers below...###
                MsgBox "Property Name: " & PropertyName & lf2 & _
                "Loan Maturity: " & .Cells(41).Value & lf2 & _
                "Lender: " & .Cells(41).Value & lf2 & _
                "Originator: " & .Cells(41).Value & lf2 & _
                "Property Address: " & .Cells(41).Value & lf2 & _
                "Note: If dates are blank, the database doesnt have the info."
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "No match found for '" & PropertyName & "'!"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. If i use this code i get the "No Match Found" message no matter which property i have selected.. Could there be an issue with my data? My original code could not match the data either if i included the "on error resume next". I think the issue is related

Comment: Just noticed there was a typo in my Match() - try it now.

Comment: unfortunately the same issue... I've tried reformatting the text, using a separate module, nothing seems to work. The code, whether yours or the  vlookup i used,  wont return any values for the categories even though a match does exist in the data (i confirmed)

Comment: Can you create a working Match formula on a worksheet?